# Simultaneous equation solver, 4 equations 4 unknowns

Tags: python

Trying to solve a system of 4 equations and 4 unknowns. Keep getting errors for "result from function call is not a proper array of floats". I am new to python so I think the issue is in my def of the equations.

I have tried fsolve, sympy.solve, and with and without a definition.

```
L0_fcc = 5200
L0_bct = 12000
L0_l = 4700
R = 8.3144

def equations(p):
        t, XSnl, XSnfcc, XSnbct = p

        GPb_fcc_bct = 489 + 3.52 * t
        GPb_fcc_l = 4810 - 8.017 * t

        GSn_bct_fcc = 5510 - 8.46 * t
        GSn_bct_l = 7179 - 14.216 * t
        GSn_fcc_l = 1661 - 5.756 * t

        E1 = sp.Eq(GPb_fcc_l + R * t * sp.log((1-XSnl)/(1-XSnfcc)) + L0_l * (XSnl**2) - L0_fcc * (XSnfcc**2))
        E2 = sp.Eq(GPb_fcc_bct + R * t * sp.log((1-XSnbct)/(1-XSnfcc)) + L0_bct * (XSnbct**2) - L0_fcc * (XSnfcc**2))
        E3 = sp.Eq(GSn_fcc_l + R * t * sp.log(XSnl/XSnfcc) + L0_l * ((1-XSnl)**2) - L0_fcc * ((1-XSnfcc)**2))
        E4 = sp.Eq(GSn_bct_l + R * t * sp.log(XSnl/XSnbct) + L0_l * ((1-XSnl)**2) - L0_bct * ((1-XSnbct)**2))
        return (E1, E2, E3, E4)


x0 = [300, 0, 0, 0]
t, XSnl, XSnfcc, XSnbct = fsolve(equations, x0)
print(t, XSnl, XSnfcc, XSnbct)`
```

It should come out with 4 values, 3 of which should be between 0 and 1. I am getting the "Result from function call is not a proper array of floats"

Comment: I assume `sp` is SciPy?

Comment: @AndrewFan 99% sure it's [SymPy](https://www.sympy.org/en/index.html) which means OP, you're passing Eq objects `(E1, E2, E3, E4)` to `scipy.optimize.fsolve` which only accepts floats, not `sp.Eq` -- that's your error.

Comment: Usually caused by [your numpy objects being something else than floats](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18184541/scipy-curve-fit-error-result-from-function-call-is-not-a-proper-array-of-floats).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you would expect `sympy` objects to interact with `scipy` solvers, they are completely different libraries. The former is symbolic objects and the latter is numerical analysis.

The solution is to simply change the following lines to:

```
E1 = (GPb_fcc_l + R * t * np.log((1-XSnl)/(1-XSnfcc)) + L0_l * (XSnl**2) - L0_fcc * (XSnfcc**2))
E2 = (GPb_fcc_bct + R * t * np.log((1-XSnbct)/(1-XSnfcc)) + L0_bct * (XSnbct**2) - L0_fcc * (XSnfcc**2))
E3 = (GSn_fcc_l + R * t * np.log(XSnl/XSnfcc) + L0_l * ((1-XSnl)**2) - L0_fcc * ((1-XSnfcc)**2))
E4 = (GSn_bct_l + R * t * np.log(XSnl/XSnbct) + L0_l * ((1-XSnl)**2) - L0_bct * ((1-XSnbct)**2))
return (E1, E2, E3, E4)
```

Now this results in a `RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in long_scalars` and a `RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in double_scalars` and finally a `RuntimeWarning: The iteration is not making good progress, as measured by the improvement from the last ten iterations.` but that's an algorithmic error which you will have to figure out on your own.

(It's almost certainly bad starting conditions since there is a `XSnl/XSnfcc == 0/0` term on the first iteration)

Finding numerical solutions to equations if often more an art than a science.